# How do constant strings work in C++

Tags: c++, string, class, memory, constructor

I have such a piece of code:

```
class temp {

private :
    char * name;
public :
    temp(char * temp_name){

        strcpy(name,temp_name);
    cout << "Created"<<name<<endl;

    }
    ~temp(){
        cout<< "Destoyed"<<name<<endl;

    }
};
int main() {
class temp person1("Jack");
class temp haha("Katy");
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to have 2 separate instances of class temp with separate names (Jack and Katy). With all Constructors and Destructors working fine. 
However, I got such a weird output:

> CreatedJack
>
> Process finished with exit code 11

I am pretty sure the problem is with constant string in the constructor temp(char * temp_name) but can't figure out what.

So my question is can you explain how, in terms of memory, is that constant string working and why I can't create 2 instances of class temp in this case?

Comment: There is no constant string in your example. This is a constant string: `const std::string s = "Hello World!";`.

Comment: This line: `strcpy(name,temp_name);` tries to copy a c-string to an non-existent buffer.  This is undefined behaviour.  You need to allocate the space for `name` before the copy.

Comment: Please also upgrade your compiler and flags. This [does not and should not compile as-is](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fceb0e73359b04dd).

Comment: Where did you lean about the syntax "class temp haha" - because that's very C

Answer (score 5):

You need to allocate buffer of sufficient size to contain passed string data and initialize `name` with a pointer to this buffer. Right now you are dereferencing uninitialized pointer `name` getting Undefined Behavior.

Also this code won't even compile because you are trying to pass a string literal into constructor expecting a pointer to non-const qualified `char`. Most likely you are using Visual Studio that allowed such non-conformant behavior for quite a long time. Starting with VS2017 you should compile with `/permissive-` to enforce conformance. And change constructor signature to

```
temp(char const * const temp_name)
```